# Backbone larger collection when loading only once - will there be big problems?

Tags: node.js, sockets, backbone.js, dataset

I have task to do where there is about 15000 items. I do it with backbone and node.js socket.io.js.

I load those items only initially, calling fetch. The script freezes for few seconds, but the everything so far is working fast.

The updated of this collection are handled using socket, so I dont need to fetch all 15K items when I want updated data.

The reason I choose this way - to get fast user interaction, so user would just search for item and it quickly is dislplayed. Not like search and wait for ajax response.

But we discussed today and my boss said the data set might grow by 10 times. I saw other discussions where its not recommended to have 100K arrays.

But when I am not going to fetch this whole data set constanly, but instead small peaces with node, how do you think will I have problems?

If so maybe I should plan to do part of data loaded, like 10K items loaded. Those items can be grouped so lets say part of groups loaded, part of groups not loaded.

So when user searches, he either gets lucky and see results instanly, or he sees ajax spinner - and data loads from server.

It felt its awesome when I dont need ajax and everything works so fast, but am bit worried when he told it might be 10x bigger data set :)

Comment: If you're noticing a performance hit on a PC, it's probably a nightmare on a tablet. How are you rendering these items? If you're smart about your DOM interaction you can speed it up, but it's still a lot of DOM nodes and a huge set of data. If you have to search over your collections that could be 10,000+ in length, you could optimize it with look-up tables in the collection based on the most common attributes of the data.

Comment: it will not be used on the tablet. It will be used in shop - as selling tickets program. And about rendering - I dont know how to say, this would probalby need code. But I just generate using underscore.js template and then place it in the container using append method. Rendering itself is not taking huge because there is like 50 items to render or so. Just need to filter those 50 items from 15K items collection currently.

Comment: that should be good. as long as you are don't render each item separately and place them all into the dom separately.

Comment: Actually there are probably various ways to optimize searches. Usually we dont need this because we use sql which optimizes itself. Or maybe there even exist some javacscript libraries which do similar thing as sql. Will need to saerch for them.

Comment: If you have the id of what you're searching for you look up on a collection with `.get(id)` or create an index or use a Backbone.ChildViewContainer and you can search against object hashes instead of looping based on whatever properties you need. (Backbone ChildViewContainer aka Backbone Babysitter https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter)

Answer (score 0):

Well your page load takes a few seconds right now - with a 10x data set increase, that will likely increase to many, many seconds, as well as increasing load on your server and DB.  Every application and data set has it's specific use, and based on that it depends on whether or not to and how you should paginate your data.  It's also risky to expose long executing methods as it makes the system more brittle and susceptible to DOS attacks.  The only client-side solution I can see for this is to fetch the data in parts or in whole and store in it local storage, but then you have to deal with that security risk.  It would likely be more difficult to implement than a standard AJAX search as well, so AJAX is likely your best bet in this situation.

Comment: the page load speed is not big problem. This application will be for shop, its not for mass ussage. So lets say worker loads this application in the morning or whatewer time he logins, it loads this data and thats it. So long loading time only once or few times a day.

Comment: If it's an internal application only and the page load speed really doesn't matter (and you know you won't have a lot of users accessing long executing processes simultaneously) then why don't you load in/seed that extra 10x amount of data and see how it performs?

Comment: yeah, I am going to try it. I now dont have this data in database but I plan to add to collections artificial data

Comment: Tried yesterday generating 117K items and there was bit lag on unrealistic cases. I mean there is like tree structure. And when parent had about 80K childs then filtering took about 4 seconds. But when I filtered to those parenths which ahave about 50 childs then it wokrs fast, about 100 ms. (At first my filtering was not optimal - but I did little optimisation and then I saw good result). Also tried with regex, similar to sql LIKE '%somehting%' and there were not big problems. So I hope I did not miss something.

Comment: Oh, btw the intial load time was increasing a lot when the biggger collection gets. For example generating first 10K items it took about 11 seconds, but when there were already 100K items and I run to generate 10K more then it takes about 2 minutes or more. So to load all 100K items on page load would be a proble. But my co worker said its ok, when there really will be that much data, then we will think.

Comment: Well the nice thing about Backbone at least is that you can easily implement this functionality by overriding that collection's fetch and get methods and the appropriate server-side code